# Magento: Attribute group as product tab

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to show different attribute groups as tab in product page. For example I have different attribute sets for different type of products, but I want depending on type of product, list attribute groups as different tabs.

Is there any out of the box solution, or I need do it by myself?

My algorithm is:

- Check attributeSet ID from product
- Collect attributeGroups of specific attributeSet
- Check if attributeGroup is listed in array of groups I want show
- Write attributeGroupName as tabName
- Collect attributeNames from attributeGroup
- Populate tabBody with attributeName -> attributeValue pairs

Any tips and help welcome! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//Set this to whatever you need to.
$allowedGroupIds = array(1,2,3,4);
//Get all groups
$groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->setAttributeSetFilter($_product->getAttributeSetId())
    ->setSortOrder()
    ->load();
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    //Skip the groups you don't need.
    if (!in_array($group->getId(), $allowedGroups)) {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<h3>'.$group->getId().' - '.$group->getAttributeGroupName().'</h3>';

    //Get attributes from the group
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
                    ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
                    ->addVisibleFilter()
                    ->checkConfigurableProducts()
                    ->load();
    if ($attributes->getSize() > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($attributes->getItems() as $attribute) {
            $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            $attrValue = $_product->getData($attrCode);
            echo '<li>';
                if (!is_array($attrValue)) {
                    echo $attrCode.' = '.$attrValue;
                } else {
                    //Do something if the attribute value is array.
                }
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: HVALA! Thanks Zoki, I think I get almost same solution.